Render BotFramework webchat in shadow dom
I have a requirement to render the webchat from BotFramework-Webchat in a shadowDom to prevent css leakage to an embedding site.
According to this GitHub Issue: BotFramework-Webchat issue 5194 and according to this PR: BotFramework-Webchat PR 5196 I should be able to render a webchat in a shadow dom. Unfortunately there is no "How to" to do so, I've tried to infer the usage from the unit tests in the PR but have not gotten it to render correctly.
Here is the short section of TS where I'm trying to render the webchat in a shadow dom.
export const startChat = async (serviceName: string, clientId?: string): Promise<void> => {
  const user = await requestToken(serviceName);
  if (user === null) return;

  webchatState.user = user;
  initializeDirectLine();

  const shadowRoot = document.body.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.id = "webchat";
  shadowRoot.appendChild(container);

  const styleOptions: WebChat.IStyleOptions = {
    avatarBorderRadius: "50%",
    avatarSize: 40,
    botAvatarBackground: getCssVariableValue("--secondary"),
    botAvatarBackgroundColor: getCssVariableValue("--secondary"),
    botAvatarImage: chatbotAvatarImg,
    botAvatarInitials: "",
    bubbleBackground: getCssVariableValue("--primary"),
    bubbleBorderRadius: "15px",
    bubbleBorderStyle: "solid",
    bubbleBorderWidth: 1,
    bubbleFromUserBackground: getCssVariableValue("--secondary"),
    bubbleFromUserBorderColor: getCssVariableValue("--primary"),
    bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: "15px",
    bubbleFromUserBorderStyle: "solid",
    bubbleFromUserBorderWidth: 1,
    bubbleFromUserTextColor: getCssVariableValue("--text-secondary"),
    bubbleTextColor: getCssVariableValue("--secondary"),
    hideUploadButton: true,
    sendBoxBackground: "White",
    sendBoxBorderBottom: "",
    sendBoxBorderLeft: "",
    sendBoxBorderRight: "",
    sendBoxBorderTop: `solid 1px ${getCssVariableValue("--primary")}`,
    sendBoxButtonColor: getCssVariableValue("--primary"),
    sendBoxHeight: 40,
    sendBoxTextColor: "Black",
    stylesRoot: shadowRoot,
    userAvatarBackgroundColor: getCssVariableValue("--secondary"),
    userAvatarImage: userAvatarImg,
    userAvatarInitials: "",
  };

  if (container !== null) {
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
        directLine: webchatState.directLine,
        userID: webchatState.user.id,
        styleOptions,
      },
      container
    );
  }
  await sendClientIdActivity(clientId);
  await sendRequestWelcomeMessage();
  await sendStartBot();
};

Here is the current result which is equal to the issue in the GitHub issue which I assume is the standard UI just without the styles that have not been applied because of the shadow dom.

Things I've checked:

The functions before the render complete successfully establishing a connection to the directline and the user information.
The botframework cdn is collecting from the latest version
The types being used are correct for the style root which needs to be recieved by the bot framework styleOptions

As reference here is the type definition for IStyleOptions which was created based on the type in the botframework repository:
interface IStyleOptions {
    [index: string]: number | string | boolean | Node;
    avatarBorderRadius: string;
    avatarSize: number;
    botAvatarBackground: string;
    botAvatarBackgroundColor: string;
    botAvatarImage: string;
    botAvatarInitials: string;
    bubbleBackground: string;
    bubbleBorderRadius: string;
    bubbleBorderStyle: string;
    bubbleBorderWidth: number;
    bubbleFromUserBackground: string;
    bubbleFromUserBorderColor: string;
    bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: string;
    bubbleFromUserBorderStyle: string;
    bubbleFromUserBorderWidth: number;
    bubbleFromUserTextColor: string;
    bubbleTextColor: string;
    hideUploadButton: boolean;
    sendBoxBackground: string;
    sendBoxBorderBottom: string;
    sendBoxBorderLeft: string;
    sendBoxBorderRight: string;
    sendBoxBorderTop: string;
    sendBoxButtonColor: string;
    sendBoxHeight: number;
    sendBoxTextColor: string;
    stylesRoot: Node;
    userAvatarBackgroundColor: string;
    userAvatarImage: string;
    userAvatarInitials: string;
  }

EDIT: I've also checked the usage of this GitHub issue which seems to render the webchat correct for the person who posted the issue : BotFramework-Webchat issue 5315. Unfortunately it does not work for me.
Updated section of code to render the shadow dom and the webchat container:
const webchatHost = document.createElement("div");
  webchatHost.id = "webchat-host";

  const shadowRoot = webchatHost.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

  const webChatContainer = document.createElement("div");
  webChatContainer.id = "webchat-container";
  webChatContainer.style.height = "200px";
  webChatContainer.style.width = "100%";

  shadowRoot.appendChild(webChatContainer);

  document.body.appendChild(webchatHost);

EDIT: It also renders the component, it's just the standard BotFramework-Webchat styles that are not working:

EDIT: @Jesus Diaz Rivero the directline is not the cause of the styles not populating.
As reference this is what it looks like when I've got a successfull render without using the shadow dom with the same function establishing a connection, 

Wouldn't initializeDirectLine need to be awaited? Are you sure it's finishing before the render?

@JesusDiazRivero I can double check it but I'm certain the connection is established, as i have a version where I don't render the webchat in a shadow dom and can have full discussions with the bot.

@JesusDiazRivero, i double checked it works fine with the directline function not being async. Check the edited section in the question description.
